# В каких случаях используется удаление в связи с низким качеством?

Tags: поддержка, тревоги

Есть следующая тревога:

> **необходимо удалить из-за проблем с качеством**
>
> Ответ имеет серьезные проблемы с форматированием или контентом. Ответ вряд ли удастся исправить с помощью правок, поэтому его необходимо удалить.

Вопрос: в каком случае она должна использоваться?

---

Спрашиваю, поскольку такая тревога на [этом ответе](//ru.stackoverflow.com/a/538168/178988) была отклонена с сообщением

> flags should not be used to indicate technical inaccuracies, or an altogether wrong answer

Ответ заведомо неверный, не работает и не может работать ни в каких ситуациях. Что с ним делать-то (кроме минуса, которых уже 4 набралось)? И зачем тогда нужна тревога о том, что ответ невозможно улучшить, если в таких случаях она неприменима?

Answer (score 4):

Эта тревога **теоретически** должна использоваться в случаях, когда ответ не имеет никакого отношения к вопросу, там написано что угодно, но не ответ, и это очевидно даже для тех, кто не знаком с предметом обсуждения. Например:

> Как сделать подвал в HTML+CSS?

> CSS не нужен. Смотрите, как круто в ExtJS. (Полотно на 100 строк.)

В остальных случаях результат зависит от того, на кого выпадет проверка. Если проверяющий (или проверяющие) разбираются в CSS, то откровенно неверный ответ может быть удалён. Если нет — ну, не повезло. `:-)`

Comment: для ответов, которые не ответы существует отдельный флаг: *"не является ответом"*. VLQ это отдельная категория, когда отвечающий имел намерение ответить на вопрос, но ответ крайне низкого качества и редактированием его не спасти.