# Какие ответы заслуживают флаг/тревогу "необходимо удалить из-за проблем с качеством"

Tags: поддержка, тревоги

Пометил [ответ](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/592812/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b7%d0%b4%d0%b5%d0%bb%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d1%81%d1%82%d1%80%d0%be%d0%ba%d1%83-%d0%bd%d0%b0-%d1%81%d0%bf%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%be%d0%ba-%d1%81%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%b2-%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b7%d0%b4%d0%b5%d0%bb%d1%91%d0%bd%d0%bd%d1%8b%d1%85-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b1%d0%b5%d0%bb%d0%b0%d0%bc%d0%b8/592910#592910) тревогой "необходимо удалить из-за проблем с качеством" так как ответ  "очень низкого качества (то есть никакая улучшающая правка не спасет сообщение)."[<sup>1</sup>](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/flag-posts)

Намерение было удалить его в два клика (мой и модератора), чтобы другим участникам не пришлось с ответом возиться. Обычно я подобные тревоги не поднимаю, чтобы модераторов не дёргать. Но случай вроде бы непротиворечивый ([ответ удалён](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/592812/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b7%d0%b4%d0%b5%d0%bb%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d1%81%d1%82%d1%80%d0%be%d0%ba%d1%83-%d0%bd%d0%b0-%d1%81%d0%bf%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%be%d0%ba-%d1%81%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%b2-%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b7%d0%b4%d0%b5%d0%bb%d1%91%d0%bd%d0%bd%d1%8b%d1%85-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b1%d0%b5%d0%bb%d0%b0%d0%bc%d0%b8/592910#592910)), но система написала в ответ:

> не следует использовать сигнал тревоги для неточных или не верных ответов.

Почему не просто минус, а именно тревога? [Цитата из изначальная задумки этого флага @Jeff Atwood♦](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/93606/137096):

> a downvote means "maybe this user is just having a bad day", a flag for low quality means this post, and possibly this user, are totally stinking up the joint and need to be ejected from the premises ASAP.

кратко: до определённой границы качества ставить минус, ниже—[удалить](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cn1XLUALTkk).

Ответ является ответом (явно присутствует намерение ответить на заданный вопрос), не является спамом или hate speech, но при этом крайне низкого качества.

**Вопрос: стоит ли VLQ тревоги поднимать?** Имеет ли смысл иметь границу/черту качества ответа, когда ответ должен быть удалён, если он не дотягивает? Или [выбранный пример ответа](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/592812/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b7%d0%b4%d0%b5%d0%bb%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d1%81%d1%82%d1%80%d0%be%d0%ba%d1%83-%d0%bd%d0%b0-%d1%81%d0%bf%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%be%d0%ba-%d1%81%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%b2-%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b7%d0%b4%d0%b5%d0%bb%d1%91%d0%bd%d0%bd%d1%8b%d1%85-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b1%d0%b5%d0%bb%d0%b0%d0%bc%d0%b8/592910#592910) неудачен (если он имеет приемлемое качество)?

Вопрос не об одном решении модератора. Вопрос в том, как мне (и другим участникам) в похожей ситуации действовать в будущем? Что лучше для сайта?

Если не поднимать тревогу, то так как участников с 20K+ репутации, которые могут удалять ответы не так много на сайте (~[25](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users?tab=Reputation&filter=all)) и вообще нет в рассматриваемой метке, то подобный ответ может так и остаться висеть (что нормально для "неточных или не верных ответов", если минус присутствует, но не нормально для ответов за рамками приемлемого качества на Stack Overflow—опции закрыть для ответа нет, поэтому при неустранимых проблемах с качеством их следует удалять).

<sub>У меня тот же вопрос что и в [В каких случаях используется удаление в связи с низким качеством?](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/3259/23044)
Там нет удовлетворительного ответа и я не вижу опции: объявить конкурс, поэтому задаю новый вопрос, чтобы привлечь внимание к теме.</sub>

Comment: от меня скорее коммент, а не ответ - тревога была вполне по теме, ответ попал в очередь VLQ, откуда выпал с результатом 6/2 (т.е. "на грани"), получил тревогу "противоречивые результаты проверки" и уже тогда был снесен вручную модератором.

Comment: Надо было минус тоже поставить.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Учитывая, что на тревогу "необходимо удалить из-за проблем с качеством" приходится смотреть нескольким людям, а не только человеку, поднявшему тревогу и модератору (как я неправильно предположил), и учитывая, что граница/черта качества ответа, когда ответ должен быть удалён, у разных людей разная, то чтобы других людей не беспокоить вместо этой тревоги *достаточно просто минус поставить в таких случаях*.

Если качество ответа очень плохое, то он достаточно быстро минусы наберёт и интерфейс уже серым помечает такие ответы.