# Тревога "Спам" - что это?

Tags: обсуждение, вопросы, спам

Что попадает под тревогу "спам"? Какие существуют точные признаки для отметки тревогой "спам" помимо краткого описания "Рекламирует продукт или услугу, не раскрывая при этом причастность автора."?

В частности, возможно ли таким образом отмечать такие вопросы, которые просто должны быть удалены, поскольку настолько далеки от сайта, что никакой "правки" они не требуют?
[Пример](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/827342/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D1%83%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%B4%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%8C-%D1%87%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD-%D0%BE%D1%82%D1%86%D0%B0), где в комментариях vp_arth даже написал "Модераторов нет - не забывайте оставлять флаг "спам" для удаления Духом". Что вполне очевидно, но этого нету в описании "спама".

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/promotion

Comment: @Suvitruf Спасибо, обновил вопрос ближе к моим мыслям)

Comment: Этот вопрос надо тревогать как "Невежливый/оскорбительный". А чуть позже голосовать за удаление.

Comment: @Suvitruf А если вопрос не являлся бы "оскорбительным"? Например, про котов? У некоторых участников (в том числе и я) есть позиция, что в данной ситуации не требуется решение модератора; вполне можно принять решение шестью тревогами.

Comment: Докладаю, вопрос уничтожен. (вж-ж-ж-ж-ж!)

Comment: @Dmig всегда можно выбрать нижнюю причину "Связать с модератором", если не уверены.

Comment: есть тревога: _необходимо удалить из-за проблем с качеством
У данного вопроса серьёзные проблемы с форматированием или содержанием. Поскольку маловероятно, что его удастся улучшить с помощью правок, этот вопрос нужно удалить._

Comment: @Grundy, нет, эта тревога не для этого. Либо спам, либо невежливооскорбительный, что вообще-то, одно и то же. Я обычно ставлю спам.

Comment: @Qwertiy, почему не для этого?там же проблемы с содержанием? проблемы - тревога подходит.

Comment: У спам есть конкретное определение https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D0%BF%D0%B0%D0%BC хорошо раскрыта тема. С помощью SO некоторые пытаются раскручивают свои сайты. Есть сервисы "клика" которые платят за публикацию спама. Тут встречалась реклама платных программ для восстановления офис-файлов, и даже реклама мусорных сообщений про софи лорен.

Comment: @Grundy, потому что только первые две тревоги минусуют и удаляют вопрос со скрытием содержимого.

Comment: @Qwertiy, ты уверен? Возможно стоит добавить чтобы и третья тоже так делала?

Comment: @Grundy, я не уверен что именно делает третья - возможно, посылает в очередь проверок на удаление. Но чтобы удалять всякую жесть, надо использовать одну из первых двух. И в любом случае, если надо скрыть тело сообщение, нужна тревога одного из первых двух видов. При обычном удалении будет показываться содержимое.

Comment: @Qwertiy, жесть жести рознь, и по идее для нее как раз и нужна третья тревога

Comment: @Grundy, нет, третья предназначена для плохих тематических вопросов.

Comment: @Qwertiy, наоборот же не тематических, плохие тематические можно отредактировать

Comment: @Qwertiy, перенеси комментарии в чат

Comment: @Grundy, позвольте узнать, было ли принято какое-то решение, или, возможно, будете открывать отдельный вопрос на тему тревог?

Comment: В чате все свелось к вопросу: [Какие ответы заслуживают флаг/тревогу “необходимо удалить из-за проблем с качеством”](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/4113/186999)

Comment: @Grundy где можно почитать? Очень уж странно: изначальный вопрос был близок к "Какую тревогу (иное средство) использовать для вопросов, которые по теме совсем мимо SO. "

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Часть нежелательных вопросов с непонятным содержанием попадают под СПАМ.

[СПАМ](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D0%BF%D0%B0%D0%BC) — массовая рассылка корреспонденции (сообщений-вопросов) рекламного или иного характера лицам, не выражавшим желания её получать.

Я бы выделил такие признаки спама

- Нужно что-то вам купить (программу или любой другой продукт, услугу)
- Нужно что-то вам узнать (а вы знали что есть новый способ, а вы знали что Маргарет, София, Маша, Андрей такие и т д)
- Нужно что-то вам посмотреть, или сделать (с опредёленным оттенком).
- Если есть слово "цена" "купить" и т.п. или к этому сводится смысл сообщения.
- Если в сообщение странный набор слов - но ведется смысл к узнать или что-то похожее - это "поисковый спам" т.е. спамеру нужно добится что б фраза с двух-трёх-десяти слов была популярна в поисковике.

По большому счёту, пользователь который вбивает сообщение, знает и понимает что он пишет. Последнее время реклама (спам) "завуалирован" под "непонятное сочетание" слов (в связи с тем, что если реклама будет слишком явной, то их сразу к СПАМ отнесут, и даже не дадут ввести сообщение-вопрос).

Есть специальные сайты, где людям дают "задание", зайди на такой-то сайт, зарегистрируйся, опубликуй там такой-то текст. За это они получают "бонусы" или "деньги" не важно. Часть вопросов - я бы отнес к таким. Но могут быть и просто люди от фирм - распространяющих рекламу.

Ещё с википедии цитата

> - Блоги, вики, форумы, доски объявлений
>
> В последнее время стали популярны веб-сайты, на которых можно оставлять     комментарии (например, форумы и блоги) или те, которые можно свободно редактировать — вики. Поскольку эти страницы открыты для свободного редактирования, на них может быть размещён спам — сплоги. Подобный спам тем более раздражает, что его труднее удалить (как правило, сообщения в форумах и блогах могут редактировать только привилегированные пользователи — соответственно, рядовой участник должен связаться с кем-нибудь из них).
>
> Спам в комментариях преследует две цели: увеличение количества входящих ссылок на продвигаемый сайт (в частности, для повышения Google PR или ТИц Яндекса), а также для увеличения посещаемости продвигаемого сайта (если комментарий оставлен на более популярном ресурсе).
>
> - Поисковый спам — страницы и web-сайты, созданные с целью манипулирования результатами в выдаче поисковых систем[20], например, дорвеи — страницы с ключевыми словами и автоматическим перенаправлением на «нужный» сайт.

Я встречал вопросы с рекламой не один раз, и как правило они сначала закрывались "как требующие правки". Возможно прочитав эту статью будет больше понимание что есть спам. Возможно под спам попадает "я это не просто не хочу читать, а и не хочу что б эту рекламу читали другие".

Тема "СПАМ" в закрытии, как мне кажется, не раскрыта. Возможно туда нужно добавить больше описания, или ссылку на описание как механизм работает.

Видя комментарии по поводу других пунктов:

- должен быть закрыт - если вопрос требует доработки, или переноса на английский сайт или на мету.
- [необходимо удалить из-за проблем с качеством](http://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/4113/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d0%be%d1%82%d0%b2%d0%b5%d1%82%d1%8b-%d0%b7%d0%b0%d1%81%d0%bb%d1%83%d0%b6%d0%b8%d0%b2%d0%b0%d1%8e%d1%82-%d1%84%d0%bb%d0%b0%d0%b3-%d1%82%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%b3%d1%83-%d0%bd%d0%b5%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%85%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%b8%d0%bc%d0%be-%d1%83%d0%b4%d0%b0%d0%bb%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%b8%d0%b7-%d0%b7%d0%b0-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b1%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%bc-%d1%81-%d0%ba%d0%b0%d1%87%d0%b5%d1%81%d1%82?noredirect=1&lq=1) - думаю что это на случай если иностранец таки писал вопрос на "своём" русском, а он написан так, что невозможно что-либо понять. Ни разу не ставил эту тревогу.
- требуется вмешательство модератора - если ситуация такая нестандартная, что вышеперечисленными методами не исправишь, но я бы обозначил, такая что может исправить модератор. Допустим если пользователь создал себе новый ник, и с него пишет те же сообщения. Если это "плагиат" такой что под дубль не попадает (встречалось), или накрутка "репутации", или другие спорные моменты, что нужно обращение к модератору.

---

Теперь о *"Модераторов нет - не забывайте оставлять флаг "спам" для удаления Духом"*.  - это механизм борьбы со спамом - 6 (шесть) учасников должны сделать тревогу с [пометкой "спам"](http://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/972/%d0%a1%d0%bf%d0%b0%d0%bc-%d0%bd%d0%b5-%d1%82%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b1%d1%83%d0%b5%d1%82-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%ba%d0%b8-%d1%81%d0%bf%d0%b0%d0%bc-%d1%82%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b1%d1%83%d0%b5%d1%82-%d0%bd%d0%b5%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%b4%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b3%d0%be-%d1%83%d0%b4%d0%b0%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%8f) - тогда вопрос будет удален без участия модератора. Не висеть с пометкой "Требует правки", а именно удалён.